# How to add margin vertically between the flex buttons and possibly justify

Tags: flexbox, margin

With this code i get the buttons spaced horizontaly. What code do i need to add to get the buttons spaced vertically (same as horizontally) when the buttons wrap ? And may be justify it ?

[image]

```
CSS

.flex-gap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-gap > div {
  margin: 10px;

}
```

HTML

```
   <div class="flex-gap">
    <div style="margin-top: 30px">
    <div class="h4 text-lg-center"><i class="fas fa-tools fa-sm fa-fw text-secondary mr-1"></i>[*tools]</div>

     <div>

        %if;(wizard and not base.has_notes)
          <div><a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MOD_NOTES">[*add base notes]</a></div>
        %end;
        %if;base.has_notes;
           <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=NOTES">
            %if;(b.base_notes_title="")
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*base notes]
            %else;%b.base_notes_title;%end;
          </a>
        %end;
        %if;has_misc_notes;
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MISC_NOTES"><i class="fa fa-indent fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*base index notes]</a>
        %end;

        <!--chroniques-->
        %if;base.has_notes;
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=NOTES&f=Chroniques_familiales"> <i class="fas fa-align-justify fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          %if;(bvar.base_notes_title="")
              [*articles]</a>
          %end;
        <!--fin chronique-->

        <!--rubriques-->
         <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=NOTES&f=1-20"><i class="fa fa-list-ol fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*chronicles]</a>
        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
          href="%prefix;m=STAT"><i class="far fa-chart-bar fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*statistics]</a>
        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary%if;(has_history and b.history="yes") mr-1%end;"
          href="%prefix;m=ANM"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*anniversaries]</a>
        %if;(has_history and b.history="yes")
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary%if;(b.disable_forum!="yes") mr-1%end;"
          href="%prefix;m=HIST&k=20"><i class="fas fa-history fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*history]</a>
        %end;


        %if;(b.propose_place_surnames!="no")
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=PPS&bi=on&ba=on&ma=on&de=on&bu=on">
            <i class="fas fa-globe fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*places]/[surname/surnames]0</a>
        %end;
        %if;(b.hide_advanced_request="no")
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=H&v=advanced">
            <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*advanced request]0</a>
        %end;
        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
          href="%prefix;m=CAL">
          <i class="far fa-calendar-alt fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*calendar/calendars]1</a>

        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
          href="http://genepoulin.net/geo/">
          [*map]</a>

        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
          href="http://genepoulin.net/gallery/">
          [*photos]</a>


              <!--forum-->

        %if;(plugin.forum and b.disable_forum!="yes")
          <a class="btn  btn-outline-primary"
            href="%prefix;m=FORUM"><i class="far fa-comments fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*forum]</a>
        %end;

       <!--fin forum-->

    </div>
    </div>
     %if;wizard;

     <div style="margin-top: 10px">
        <div class="h4 text-lg-center"><i class="fas fa-tools fa-sm fa-fw text-secondary mr-1"></i>[*books]</div>

       <div>
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA&data=fn"
            title="[*modify] %apply;book_of%with;[first name/first names]1%end;%sp;
              ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*first name/first names]1</a>
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA&data=sn"
            title="[*modify] %apply;book_of%with;[surname/surnames]1%end;%sp;
              ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*surname/surnames]1</a>
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA&data=place"
            title="[*modify] %apply;book_of%with;[places]%end;%sp;
              ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*places]</a>
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA&data=occu"
            title="[*modify] %apply;book_of%with;[occupation/occupations]1%end;%sp;
              ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*occupation/occupations]1</a>
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA&data=src"
            title="[*modify] %apply;book_of%with;[source/sources]1%end;%sp;
              ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*source/sources]1</a>

          %if;(wizard and b.propose_add_family!="no")
          <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
            href="%prefix;m=ADD_FAM"
            title="[*add::family/families]0 ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)"><i class="fas fa-user-plus mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        %end;


          %if;((b.wizard_passwd_file!="" or b.wizard_descr_file!="")
             and (wizard or wiznotes_dir_exists)
             and b.authorized_wizards_notes="yes")
           <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
            href="%prefix;m=WIZNOTES"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-fw mr-1"></i></a>
        %end;

     </div>
     </div>
     </div> <!--flex gap-->
```